# 24V to 5V DC conversion for Raspberry Pi

Tags: power-supply, dc, raspberry-pi, conversion

I'm trying to power several devices off of a breadboard. For simplicity I want to power these all from the same PSU. The highest voltage amongst the devices is 24V. I was looking to use a 24V 2A (maybe 3A) DC PSU to power all of these.

I'm wondering how I could do this? I've seen [these](http://cpc.farnell.com/1/1/116533-10w-reg-dip-24v-5v-out-10pwrb2405d-powerpax.html) and wondered if they would achieve what I want (I realize I might have to build in a regulation circuit for the Pi with this).

Comment: "I'm trying to power several devices **off of a** breadboard" - what does that mean? do you mean "from a breadboard" or do you mean "there are several devices on the breadboard that need powering"?

Comment: The question is unclear.  What are you implying when you are saying "highest voltage amongst the devices is 24V"?  What are those devices?  Can you post a block diagram?

Comment: If you are just breadboarding, just get an additional 5v power supply for $5 off digikey or cannibalize a USB charger adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use those cheap LM2596 based DC/DC converter modules, from ebay. They worked fine for me.

Be sure to set the converter output voltage BEFORE powering on.